# TLS extenstion pre_sharek_key

Tags: ssl, https, tls-psk

Can anyone explain to me what is pre_shared_key TLS extension and what is it relation with Session Ticket TLS extension because I observed that when the pre_shared_key extension is present in the TLS Client Hello message the Session Ticket extension is absent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... when the pre_shared_key extension is present in the TLS Client Hello message the Session Ticket extension is absent

The first one is session resumption with TLS 1.3, the second with TLS 1.2 and lower. There are several information about this protocol change on the internet, like [TLS Session Resumption TLS 1.3 uses 0-RTT Handshakes](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/TLS%20Session%20Resumption#section-TLS+Session+Resumption-TLSSessionResumptionTLS1.3Uses0RTTHandshakes).

Comment: Why we can find the Session Ticket extension in TLS 1.3 Client Hello messages?

Comment: @AlaJebnoun: A TLS 1.3 client usually can do TLS 1.2 too and does not know yet which protocol version the server supports - so it will offer this kind of session resume too for older TLS protocol versions.